# Are HTTP and HTTPS default port numbers defined in the JDK?

Tags: java, http

I've hunted around a bit trying to see if port 80 and port 443 are defined as public constants anywhere.  Do these exist in the JDK (or perhaps in a common library such as Apache HttpClient)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at Javadoc for URL: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getDefaultPort--

`getDefaultPort()` returns the port for the given protocol

```
URL url = new URL("http://blah.com");
int defaultPort = url.getDefaultPort();
```

Answer (score 4):

Apache HttpClient does have them as integer constants:

- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpURL.html#DEFAULT_PORT
- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpsURL.html#DEFAULT_PORT

Comment: I cannot find them in the much refactored version 4

Comment: in apache v4, it uses `DefaultSchemePortResolver.resolve(HttpHost host)` which returns the integer for the port number, given the schema -- https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultSchemePortResolver.html