# HTTP and HTTPS default port number constants in java

Tags: java, port, constants

Usually Java comes along with a large set of sensible constants to use. HTTP and HTTPS default port numbers as assigned by IANA (80 and 443) would be sensible constants. I checked the javadoc of java.net.URL, java.net.HttpURLConnection and javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection but didn’t find them there. Are those constants somewhere in the JavaSE? If not, are they somewhere available in the classes a web application on Tomcat has access to, e.g. org.apace.catalina or coyote? Just because I don’t like magic numbers in my code…

Do I have to do this in URL composition?

```
if(port != new URL("http://example.com/").getDefaultPort() &&
        port != new URL("https://example.com/").getDefaultPort()){
    stringBuilder.append(":");
    stringBuilder.append(port);
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498275/are-http-and-https-default-port-numbers-defined-in-the-jdk I don't think there are standard defined constants in java for port numbers.

Comment: Just insert the port number every time

Comment: Also, don't use a `StringBuilder` to build URLs, use the `URI` class. It can do the job of encoding for you. And it has many constructors, including one taking a host/port number

Comment: In the case of HTTP(S) ports, I don't think anyone has a problem with magic numbers. Declare them as constants and i don't see a problem. These numbers are not gonna change without the internet being rebuilt.

Comment: @fge: Thanks for the `URI`. Not really nice yet but really much better: `String url = new URI(port == 443 ? "https" : "http", null, host, (port == 80 || port == 443) ? -1 : port, (path != null && path.length() > 0) ? path : "/", null, null).toString();` ☺

Answer (score 5):

Apache HttpClient has them, if this is a library you use:

- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpURL.html#DEFAULT_PORT
- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpsURL.html#DEFAULT_PORT

Comment: cannot find them in the much refactored version 4