# request.getScheme() is returning http instead of returning https in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
function demo(request,response){
        request.getScheme() is returning http instead of returning https.
        System.out.println(""+request.getScheme());
}
```

output:http

--above function demo is being called from main method but it prints http instead it should        print https while working on internet server.

Comment: can you verify what is full uri by using request.getRequestURI()in function

Comment: This does not look like Java.

Comment: on the basis of scheme i am making a url to hit a new link from my application but because i am getting http from request.getScheme().i am unable to make correct url path.   @Henry this is demo function.. use to ask question.. sry for not commenting //is returning http instead of returning https

Answer (score 10):

If your server is running behind a proxy server, make sure your proxy header is set:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
```

Then to get the right `scheme` you can use springframework's classes:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new ServletServerHttpRequest(request); //request is HttpServletRequest
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(httpRequest).build();

String scheme = uriComponents.getScheme(); // http/https
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I was stuck in this situation for 2 days. :)

Answer (score 6):

See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599143/1524502, and note the issues about being behind a reverse proxy or load balancer. Most likely, that is your problem.

The answerer in that question recommended using

```
request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto")
```

instead, though that is dependent on your load balancer setting the header correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have a similar problem with getScheme()

```
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
```

I've solved using "//" instead:

```
String basePath = "//"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
```