# How to retrieve port number from a tomcat server sitting behind a load-balancer

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jboss, port

*Situation:*

- My client has a Java web application deployed on a JBoss server, it is accessed both via **HTTPS** and **HTTP**
- The JBoss server is sitting behind a load-balancer that handles the SSL, in other words this load-balancer **terminates** SSL and sends requests to JBoss as plain **HTTP**

*Problem I need to solve:*

The web application deployed on JBoss needs to know what port the load-balancer is using for **HTTPS**, so that it can direct users to certain HTTPS urls correctly. This cannot be hard-coded because the application will be deployed on multiple clients, each of them have different configurations for the load-balancer.

*My approach (which didn't work)*:

I am defining the port from a jspx page, via `${pageContext.request.serverPort}`, but this always returns the port for HTTP because JBoss always gets the request via HTTP.

Thanks in advance. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599143/5232319) question but was not helpful.

Comment: Use urls of the form `://` (without a protocol or port) and the client will preserve the current protocol and port.

Comment: Hey @ElliottFrisch, it doesn't make sense for me to not include a protocol because I need to explicitly direct users to a url with https protocol (normally the website is accessed via http). Thanks!

Comment: In links on pages the `://` trick works (i.e. http and https will continue to function), as for redirecting certain urls that sounds like something you could extract to configuration.

Comment: If you aren't using port 443 for HTTPS you should be. In which case you can omit it altogether.

Comment: Cheers guys, I guess I'll have to setup a property for the clients to configure according to their needs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a way to determine the port if tomcat is sitting behind a load balancer. As suggested in the comments, exposing the port configuration to your clients would be the best for now.