# Wicket incorrect bookmarkable page url when using https

Tags: java, apache, nginx, https, wicket

I have two pages:

- PageA.html
- PageB.html

PageA contains a link to PageB, specified this way:

```
add(new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("link", PageB.class, parameters));
```

This works perfectly fine as long as PageB is just a regular http page. The link url on PageA is displayed as "http://www.example.com/PageB".

The problem occurs when I change PageB to require https, like so:

```
@RequireHttps
public class PageB extends WebPage {
    ...
}
```

Now, suddenly the link url on PageA uses the local ip instead of the domain name, this way "https://127.0.0.1/PageB". This means that the visitors on my site cannot access PageB since the url is incorrect.

How come it uses the local ip in the url when PageB uses "@RequireHttps"?
I would like the url to use the domain name as before, and only change protocol from http to https.

I am running my webapp in Tomcat 7 under Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue has now been solved. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32090722/1826061

Basically, I updated my nginx config like so:

```
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
```

And then I added this Valve to my Tomcat config:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"  
       remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"  
       protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"  
       protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https"/>
```

Hopefully it might help others that got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

HttpsMapper uses `HttpServletRequest#getServerName()` to create an absolute URL, you'll have to ajdust the name of the `<host>` element in `server.xml`.

Comment: I changed the name of the host from:
`<Host name="localhost" ....>`
To:
`<Host name="example.com" ....>`. It did not help.

Still got the same problem with the url in the link being 127.0.0.1.`